# TypeOrm - Nest.js Failed to connect to XX:1433 - self signed certificate

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

When trying to connect to SQL Server, I get the following error:

```
[Nest] 96151  - 30/07/2021 18:28:34   ERROR [TypeOrmModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to XXXXXX:1433 - self signed certificate*
```

My ormconfig.json:

```json
{
    "type": "mssql",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 1433,
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass",
    "database": "BDname",
    "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    "synchronize": true
}
```

Answer (score 12):

add this line to your code in typeorm config. options: { encrypt: false }

your config code would be something like this:

`type: 'mssql',
host: 'localhost',
port: 1433,
username: 'sa',
password: '@Yourpassword123',
database: 'yourdatabase',
autoLoadEntities: true,
synchronize: true,
options: { encrypt: false },`

I used "sa" as user because its default user name for sql server. Adapt the code config above as you need!

Answer (score 7):

You just need to add in ormconfig.json and works for me

> "options": {"trustServerCertificate": true}

```js
{
    "type": "mssql",
    "host": "XXXXXX",
    "port": 1433,
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass",
    "database": "BDName",
    "entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
    "synchronize": true,
    "options": {"trustServerCertificate": true}   
}
```

Comment: Congrats! Since you've solved the issue can you set this answer as **Accepted Answer**. Thanks!

Comment: This is such a life saver haah